# What is the issue with the following code/practice in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

In my Angular Controller, I use the following...

```
    $scope.selectedAll = { all: false};
```

Later in the template, it is bound like so...

```
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll.all" ng-click="checkAll()"/> All
```

Things work as I expect it to. Basically, the selectedAll2 remains false. However, I tried to change the controller's code to...

```
    $scope.selectedAll2 = false;
```

And bound it in the template like so...

```
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll2" ng-click="checkAll()"/> All
```

It doesn't work as I expect it to. What am I missing? Please suggest if there is fundamentally something wrong or why I shouldn't try to directly bind to the scope variables.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z21qfwqz/22/ ?

Comment: @RahulSoni, there is nothing wrong with your example as Igor Semin's jsFiddle has demonstrated. You may have another issue, so I suggest you to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem and host it in jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I guess it is happening due to ui-router... I can see this issue only in the child templates. Will try to create a fiddle. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In your first case, you are using a "parent" scope (*$scope.selectedAll*) with a child scope property *all*.

When a parent scope has a field , the child scope property will be inherited.

In second case, you are using only the primitive *selectedAll2* .

What's the problem?

**Primitives can be only used for read, not to write a value.**
In this case, you are hiding the parent scope and the issue will happen.

This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of always have a '.' in your [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

You have to understand how scopes work. Take a look on this [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).
After you read and watch the related links on article, I think it will be clear enough to understand the problem.

I hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: I will be thankfull if somebody explain me why I get the negative score, because I put also the related links to complete answer. Thank you.